# "Missing EOF AT GROUP..." when i'm trying do a query with group by in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, group-by, cql, nosql

i'm trying to do a query in CQL as follows:

```
SELECT column1 FROM mytable WHERE column2=value GROUP BY column3;
```

My table is the following:

```
 CREATE TABLE mytable( 
 column1 text
 column2 text
 column3 text
 primary key (column1,column2,column3));
```

And i'm getting the following error:

> SyntaxException: line 1:48 missing EOF at 'GROUP' (...FROM mytable WHERE columns2=value [GROUP] BY...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a bad error description, but essentially that statement is not valid CQL.  Cassandra does not support `GROUP BY` operations.

However, this was addressed in [CASSANDRA-10707](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10707), and is slated to be released with Cassandra 3.10.

Comment: are you sure ? . i found this : [link](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/dml.html)

Comment: @M.Doe As sure as the patch release number in the JIRA ticket.  Hey, if you can get it to work, more power to ya!  But from what I'm seeing, that functionality isn't available (unless you've built from source).

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Aaron